# Como usar replace() para a última ocorrência?

Tags: java, android, string, regex

O método `String#replaceFirst()` é utilizado para substituir a primeira ocorrência de uma *substring* numa *string*, mas como devo proceder caso eu queira fazer isso com a **última** ocorrência?

A duvida é o seguinte como vou fazer a condição para analisar a *string* e se encontrar palavra utilizar o métodos apresentados.

Aqui apaga ultimo caractere digitado.

```
    texto = txtTexto.getText().toString();
        int length = texto.length();  
         txtTexto.setText(texto.substring(0, length-1));
```

Aqui analisa condição para apagar um palavra inteira.

```
if (texto.substring(length-3, length).equals("sin")){

    txtTexto.setText(replaceLast(texto, "sin", ""));   
    }
    else if if (texto.substring(length-4, length).equals("asin")){

    txtTexto.setText(replaceLast(texto, "asin", ""));
    }
```

Desse jeito funciona no **sin**, mas quando cai na outra condição elimina o **sin** e mantém o ***a*** na tela, se inverter a ordem a condição do  **sin** funciona o **asin** sendo assim caracteres menores, tipo 2 caracteres não funcionam.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma outra alternativa seria utilizar o método [`String#substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

```java
public static String replaceLast(String texto, String substituir, String substituto) {
    // Retorna o índice da última ocorrência de "substituir"
    int pos = texto.lastIndexOf(substituir); 
    // Se encontrar o índice
    if (pos > -1) { 
       // Retorna os caracteres antecedentes de "substituir"
       return texto.substring(0, pos) 
        + substituto
        // Retorna os caracteres posteriores a "substituir"
        + texto.substring(pos + substituir.length(), texto.length()); 
    } else 
       // Se a palavra especificada em "substituir" não for encontrada não altera nada
       return texto;
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```java
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(replaceLast("foobarfoobar", "foo", "")); // foobarbar
}
```

Resposta baseada [nessa resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282982/1608936).

Comment: @Rodolfo Como assim? se quiser substituir o último `asin` basta especifica-lo no segundo parâmetro da função.

Comment: de olhada na pergunta editada.

Comment: @Rodolfo Veja se é [**isso**](https://ideone.com/CmUT8T) o que você quer fazer.

Answer (score 4):

Há uma solução pronta [nessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1660047/221800):

```
public static String replaceLast(string text, string source, string target) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(text);
    b.replace(text.lastIndexOf(source), text.lastIndexOf(source) + source.length(), target);
    return b.toString();
}
```

Na mesma pergunta tem outra resposta que utiliza RegEx e é até mais condizente como o `replaceFirst()`:

```
public static String replaceLast(String text, String regex, String replacement) {
    return text.replaceFirst("(?s)(.*)" + regex, "$1" + replacement);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/ReplaceLast.cs).

Comment: Eu não tenho como ver se está tudo como você quer porque a pergunta não consta mais detalhes, não consta um código com exemplo de como deveria ser testando e o resultado esperado. Se você melhorar a pergunta, eu posso melhorar a resposta.

Comment: de olhada na pergunta editada.

Comment: @Rodolfo mas com o que você está testando? Qual é o valor de `texto`. Talvez o que você quer não é um `replaceLast()`, sua pergunta claramente pediu por ele e as duas respostas te deram isto.

Comment: texto é um String, é  o seguinte  cabei fazendo outra pergunta para saber se esta certo o que eu estou fazendo só colocar o replaceLast nao esta resolve precisa de uma condição

Comment: @Rodolfo infelizmente não estou entendo o que você está escrevendo, seu texto é muito confuso. Tente ser mais claro para eu poder te ajudar. E faça o que eu lhe falei. Exite a pergunta para mostrar como podemos testar o problema que você está enfrentando. Pra mim, está tudo certo, você tem que demonstrar o que está errado. De qualquer forma, a pergunta feita foi respondida, estamos só tentando ajudar no seu outro problema, o que talvez exija que outra pergunta seja aberta.

Comment: @bigown, eu acredito que ele esteja querendo verificar se no texto contém uma certa palavra, para depois, substituir ela.

Comment: @array pode ser, se for, o problema é completamente outro e então a pergunta original já foi respondida e para o outro problema precisa de uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo tendo duas respostas que "solucionam seu problema", vou tentar deixar uma para complementar e solucionar de vez o seu erro.

```
String[] toRemove = {"sin", "asin", "whatever_you_want", "hi"};

for (String isRemovable : toRemove){
    if (textTexto.contains(isRemovable){
        txtTexto.setText(replaceLast(texto, isRemovable, ""));
        break;
    } else {
        // code
    }
}
```

Com isso, o código vai verificar se sua `EditText` contém uma das palavras presentes em `toRemove`. Se sim, a palavra será removida.